# when I call a function it returns a random valued array instead of the "right one"

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, clion

I'm trying to improve myself in competitive programming and I'm trying to do a easy task in a hard way.
I'm trying to split an array in two arrays (even and odd positions), apply the QuickSort on each of the two and then putting them together once again.

But I have some wrong output, probably I'm getting something wrong with pointers.

```
int arr[5] = {5, 4, 1, 3, 2};
int** a;
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
a = makearrs(arr, size);
```

Here's where I call the function *makearrs* passing it the array and the fixed size (I could pass 5 but I just calculated it).

Here's the function *makearrs*

```
int** makearrs(int* arr, int size){
int size_arr = size / 2;
int even_arr[size_arr + 1];  //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
int pair_arr[size_arr + 1];
// Inizializzo
for(int i = 0; i<=size_arr; i++){
    even_arr[i] = 0;
    pair_arr[i] = 0;
}
int j = 0;
for(int i=0; i<size; i = i+2){          //Lettura sicura, va bene per entrambi i casi.
    pair_arr[j] = arr[i];
        if(i+1 != size) {
            even_arr[j] = arr[i + 1];
        }
    j++;
}
int ** a = makepairs(pair_arr, even_arr);
return a;
```

And finally the function *makepairs* which creates an array of pointers (two-sized) containing the two arrays (even and odd position array).

```
int** makepairs(int* arr, int* arr2) {
int** ptr = new int*[2];
ptr[0] = arr;
ptr[1] = arr2;
return ptr;
```

If I try to for-print the resulting

```
 int * even;
even = a[1];
int * pair;
pair = a[0];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    cout << even[i];
    cout << "\n";
    cout << pair[i];
    cout << "\n";
```

I get this output:
4
47398584
1
1
-325478504
47398584

Comment: `int even_arr[size_arr + 1];` and `int pair_arr[size_arr + 1];` are not even valid C++. Your C++ compiler has a non-standard extension that allows this kind of code, but this is not valid C++, and other C++ compilers will refuse to compile this. Which C++ textbook are you using, that gives examples of code that looks like this? You should seriously consider throwing it away and getting a better textbook, that will help you learn standard C++.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning pointers to the `even_arr` and `pair_arr` arrays. But as soon as the function returns, those arrays no longer exist. So it is an error to dereference the pointers to them.

```
int** makepairs(int* arr, int* arr2) {
int** ptr = new int*[2];
ptr[0] = arr;
ptr[1] = arr2;
return ptr;
```

So this allocates a new array and puts two values in it, each a pointer to an array. But:

```
int ** a = makepairs(pair_arr, even_arr);
return a;
```

Here you pass it `pair_arr` and `even_arr`, causing it to create an array with pointers to those two objects -- objects created locally on a stack that will be destroyed by the `return` statement immediately following.

Any attempt to dereference those pointers *after* the `return` is an error since they are pointers to arrays that no longer exist. (If you think they still exist, try to show where they were allocated and how they could be freed. It cannot be done.)

You should use `std::vector` instead to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning pointers to local variables. Those local variables cease to exist after your function returns, so the pointers are invalid. Any use of those pointers means your program has undefined behaviour.

Not only that, you don't have a C++ program.

```
int size_arr = size / 2;
int even_arr[size_arr + 1]; // This is not C++, size_arr needs to be a compile-time constant
```